# Postgresql Arel and Group By

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I made this method on my local using arel to create my own search.

```
def self.search(search)
    User.joins(:experience).where(Experience.arel_table[:description].matches("%#{search}%")
            .or(Experience.arel_table[:description].matches("%#{search.capitalize}%"))
            .or(Experience.arel_table[:job_title].matches("%#{search}%"))
            .or(Experience.arel_table[:job_title].matches("%#{search.capitalize}%")))
            .group(:user_id)
end
```

everything works great, until a push to heroku.

Heroku Logs show me the following message:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (PGError: ERROR:  column "users.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
```

This is the select:

```
SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" INNER JOIN "experiences" ON "experiences"."user_id" = "users"."id" WHERE (((("experiences"."description" ILIKE '%rails%' OR "experiences"."description" ILIKE '%Rails%') OR "experiences"."job_title" ILIKE '%rails%') OR "experiences"."job_title" ILIKE '%Rails%')) GROUP BY user_id ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 7 OFFSET 0):
```

As you can see, I have the .group(:user_id) in my method, so I don't undertand this error

Thanks in advance for your help.

UPDATE

after I change the method like this:

```
User.joins(:experience).where(Experience.arel_table[:description].matches("%#{search}%")
.or(Experience.arel_table[:description].matches("%#{search.capitalize}%"))
.or(Experience.arel_table[:job_title].matches("%#{search}%"))
.or(Experience.arel_table[:job_title].matches("%#{search.capitalize}%")))
.select("experiences.user_id, users.email")
.group("experiences.user_id, users.email")
```

I get this error in my view

```
undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass
```

in this line

```
<%= user.information.name %>
```

If I erase this line I get this error

```
Routing Error

No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"users", :id=>#<User email: "jgiron@hotmail.com">}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to do a `select`.

```
User.joins(:experience).where(Experience.arel_table[:description].matches("%#{search}%")
        .or(Experience.arel_table[:description].matches("%#{search.capitalize}%"))
        .or(Experience.arel_table[:job_title].matches("%#{search}%"))
        .or(Experience.arel_table[:job_title].matches("%#{search.capitalize}%")))
        .select("experiences.user_id, users.email")
        .group("experiences.user_id, users.email")
```

If you do not specify which columns to select, Rails will, by default, try to select all of the columns.

**Update**

When doing SQL queries, all fields that show up in `SELECT` must show up in the `GROUP BY`.  So if you have `SELECT foo, bar, baz, MAX(id) FROM foo_bars GROUP BY foo, bar, baz`, then `foo`, `bar` and `baz` must be in the `GROUP BY`.  Since `MAX(id)` is an aggregate function, it does not have to appear in the `GROUP BY`.

However, if you are not trying to do this kind of `GROUP BY`, then Rails has an application-side method called `group_by`.  You use it like this:

```
@experiences.group_by {|x| x.user_id}
```

Which will return a hash with the key as the user id, and the value as the experience.

Comment: What doesn't work?  You will need to select all of the fields that you need, just like a normal SQL query.  `.select("user_id, email").group(:user_id, :email)`

Comment: this is the error SQLite3::SQLException: ambiguous column name: created_at: SELECT  user_id, email FROM "users" INNER JOIN "experiences" ON "experiences"."user_id" = "users"."id" WHERE (((("experiences"."description" LIKE '%perra%' OR "experiences"."description" LIKE '%Perra%') OR "experiences"."job_title" LIKE '%perra%') OR "experiences"."job_title" LIKE '%Perra%')) GROUP BY user_id, email ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 7 OFFSET 0

Comment: In that case, you will have to do `.select("experiences.user_id, users.email").group("experiences.user_id, users.email")`

Comment: Thanks Sean, but I get the same error, but now with this columns

Comment: The same error as what?  The ambiguous column errors?  That cannot be possible.

Comment: I'm wondering if a group by is even necessary here since you are not selecting experiences... you're only selecting users.

Comment: I think yes, because I not I get the same result multiple times, for example if the experiences is "developer" a user can appear many times if he has many experiences with the word "developer"

Comment: Sean I change the group with the uniq http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-uniq and It works, But I don't understand why. Thanks anyway